# Set default value of JSwing checkbox?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, itemlistener

I currently have an actionListener set up to detect whether or not the checkBox I have created is checked, and depending on this; set the value of taskType to either 'oneOff' (unchecked) or 'Routine (checked). The problem is that when the user submits the form by clicking the button, the received value is 'null' if the box is left unchecked, the only way to make the received value 'oneOff' is by checking the box and unchecking it again. How can I make the default unchecked value of the checkbox 'oneOff' - and is this even possible?

```
checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

            if(freqComboBox.getSelectedIndex() == -1  && checkBox.isSelected())
            {
                freqLabel.setEnabled(true);
                freqComboBox.setEnabled(true);
                createTask.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else if(checkBox.isSelected())
            {
                freqLabel.setEnabled(true);
                freqComboBox.setEnabled(true);
                taskType = "Routine";
            }
            else
            {
                freqLabel.setEnabled(false);
                freqComboBox.setEnabled(false);
                freqComboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
                taskType = "oneOff";
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `How can I make the default unchecked value of the checkbox 'oneOff' - and is this even possible?` - you set the value when you define the variable. If you don't set the value, the it defaults to null. This is basic Java.

Comment: Why not set the initial value of `taskType` to `"oneOff"`? or since it's a binary (yes/no) input, why not just use a `boolean`, i.e. `checkBox.isSelected()` and convert when (and if) needed, e.g. for display purposes?

Comment: Im actually an idiot. It's been a long day haha, thanks for helping me out though. @d.j.brown